# Convert template in .hbs to .jsx

Tags: templates, jsx, hbs

I have a template file in .hbs, i need to convert to .jsx , but i have difficulty in the if else condition for th element in table.

This is in .hbs

```
  <tr>
  <th> Amount </th>
  {{#if show_trust}}
     <th>
         Trust Account
     </th>
     <th>
         Trust Balance
     </th>
  {{/if}}
  </tr>
```

What I have tried in .jsx, one of them is below.

```
<tr>
<th> Amount </th>
{show_trust && <th>Trust Account</th>}
{show_trust && <th>Trust Balance</th>}
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found working solution in jsx but could be more elegant

```js
<tr>
<th> Amount </th>
{(() => {
          if (show_trust) {
                   return (
                       <th>Trust Account</th>
                   )
               }
           })()}
           
{(() => {
               if (show_trust) {
                   return (
                       <th>Trust Balance</th>
                   )
               }
         })()}
</tr>
```